# "He is more than a friend is"

Tags: ellipsis, comparative

**(1a)** *He is taller than his friend*. — correct
**(1b)** *He is taller than his friend **is***. — as I know, (1b) is also correct, although less common than (1a)

**(2a)** *He is more than a friend*. — correct
**(2b)** *He is more than a friend **is***. — by analogy with (1b), (2b) must be correct too. Is it so? If not, then why is (2b) not correct, whereas (1b) that is analogous to (2b) is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, because "than" can be a conjunction or a preposition, and not everyone agrees on when it is each. I'll present one interpretation that I believe is pretty standard.

In 1a and 1b, "than" is best understood as a conjunction. It compares two actions ("he is taller" and "his friend is tall"). That is why we can insert "is" at the end of 1b.

In 2a and 2b, "than" is best understood as a preposition. The prepositional phrase "than a friend" modifies "more". It does *not* compare two actions ("he is more" and "a friend is [adjective]"). That is why we can not insert "is" at the end of 2b.

To summarize: In your sentences 1a and 1b, "than" is a conjunction. In 2a and 2b, it is a preposition. Thus, the situations are not analogous.

Answer (score 5):

2b is not correct. The analogy is misleading

In the first set, the form is: {subject} is {adjective in comparative form} than {other than subject} [is {adjective in non-comparative form}].

> He is taller than his friend

equates to

> He is taller than his friend is tall.

We can fill out the final clause with the non-comparative form of the adjective previously used.

But in the second set, we have no adjective describing a difference in attributes, nor are we comparing two different persons. The structure is {subject} is more than {noun}

> He is more than a friend

The thought is incomplete, and there is no way to create an obvious final clause.

Suppose the full thought is

> He is more than a friend; he is her husband.

Saying

> He is more than a friend is her husband

is not even grammatical.

Analogies in language are dangerous; language does not consistently follow the rules of formal logic, and very small differences in wording can have large differences in meaning.

Comment: You wrote the sentence "_He is taller than his friend is tall_.". But it's written [here](https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst218948_He-is-taller-than-his-friend-is-tall-.aspx) that it's incorrect. As I understand, you disagree and consider this sentence correct, right?

Comment: I do consider it grammatically correct. It is not highly idiomatic because this is a situation where ellipsis is very frequent. In fact, I think your citation is utter nonsense,

Comment: "_I think your citation is utter nonsense_" - your reaction is negative. I didn't want to hurt you. The only reason of my citation is that translation of this sentence into my native language doesn't make any sense. That's why I necessarily needed to find out about its correctness in more detail.

Comment: I am not hurt. I am not offended. I am frank. When I am confident that something is wrong, I say so. I did not mean to upset you by speaking honestly.

Comment: "_ your citation is utter nonsense_" - this phrase means you strongly didn't like what I wrote. Could you explain, as befits adequate people, the reason of it? Because when you don't explain the reason of your such a negative reaction, it looks like more an insult than a normal dialogue.

Comment: @Loviii it's an insult to the things written in the article you link, not an insult to you.

Comment: @Loviii No insult to you was intended. I am sorry you took offense. It is the article that you mentioned that I was disparaging, **NOT YOU**.

Answer (score -1):

(1a) He is taller than his friend. — correct, but incomplete, and natural
(1b) He is taller than his friend is. — correct, but incomplete, and natural

(1c) He is taller than his friend is tall.  - correct and complete, but awkward

(2a) He is more than a friend. — correct, but incomplete, and natural
(2b) He is more than a friend is. - correct, but incomplete, and awkward

(2c) He is more than a friend to me. - correct, but incomplete, and natural
(2d) He is more than a friend is to me. - correct, but incomplete, and awkward
(2e) He is more to me than a friend is to me - correct, complete, and awkward

The complete statement of meaning is grammatically correct but may be more, or longer, than people naturally say.  Typically words that can be implied are eliminated for more natural speech.  Some eliminations of implied words will lead to constructions that are grammatically correct and natural, while other eliminations of implied words can lead to constructions that are grammatically correct but which sound awkward.  The awkwardness of an expression has more to do with common usage than it does with rules of grammar.

Comment: If we separate your (1a-d), proceeding from their sense, we can see two meanings: the first one, having one fact, is "_His height is more than his friend's height_"; the second one, having two facts, is "_His height is more than his friend's height + His friend is tall_". As I understand, (1a)&(1b) only has the first meaning and (1c)&(1d) has the second one. Could you tell me I am right? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii  Actually, the original 1a/1b do not imply his friend is tall; it could be that his friend is short but he is taller (and still short).  That was my error and I have edited.

Comment: And as to (1c), does it imply his friend is tall?

Comment: @Loviii No - "tall" there is just part of the comparison.  What is he taller than?  He is taller than the tallness of his friend - taller "than his friend is tall".  It is not asserting that his friend actually IS tall.  It is using "tall" in the same way I can ask "How tall is he?" to mean "What is his height?" without saying that he actually is tall.

Comment: Will (1c) remain correct if we add something between "_is_" and "_tall_"? For instance, "_five feet_": _He is taller than his friend is **five feet** tall_. Thanks

Comment: @Loviii As written, no, the comparison won't work in that case.  However, you can say _He is taller than his friend, **who** is **five feet** tall_.  This significantly changes the meaning though.  In the original I am comparing his height to his friend's height.  In the second I am comparing him to his friend.